# Too Large Frame issue:17882426381 in spark 1.6

Tags: apache-spark

Facing too large frame issue, increased shuffle partitions (runned from 200 to 2001) and executor memory up to (50G) and executor memory overhead - 20480 still it is failing

Also used repartition,persist technical terms still it is showing same error

Data size: 300+ million

[image]